# Batch DBF files into CSV files in Python

Tags: python, dbf

There are previous topics on this, however, the codes presented are not correct.

Could anyone post a reliable code for batch processing dbf's into csv?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Unless you show [some research effort](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) in your question it is likely to be closed as "too broad". What have you tried and what kind of problem did you get?

Answer (score 0):

I had a bunch of (non-GIS) DBF files that I needed to convert into different formats (CSV, DataFrames, HDF, SQL, etc.), so I wrote a minimal conversion module called [simpledbf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simpledbf/0.2.4). It doesn't do anything fancy, but it will convert to CSV using Python >=2.7 and >=3.4 without any additional dependencies.

For example, you could do something like this (not tested):

```
import os
from simpledbf import Dbf5
all_files = os.listdir('.')
dbfs = [f for f in all_files if f.endswith('dbf')]
for dbf in dbfs:
    data = Dbf5(dbf)
    data.to_csv(dbf[:-3] + 'csv')
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

[This code worked](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93303/bulk-convert-dbf-to-csv-in-a-folder-arcgis-10-1-using-python).

import os
import arcpy
import csv

def dbf2csv(dbfpath, csvpath):
    ''' To convert .dbf file or any shapefile/featureclass to csv file
    Inputs: 
        dbfpath: full path to .dbf file [input] or featureclass
        csvpath: full path to .csv file [output]

```
'''
#import csv
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(dbfpath)
csvFile = csv.writer(open(csvpath, 'wb')) #output csv
fieldnames = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(dbfpath)]

allRows = []
for row in rows:
    rowlist = []
    for field in fieldnames:
        rowlist.append(row.getValue(field))
    allRows.append(rowlist)

csvFile.writerow(fieldnames)
for row in allRows:
    csvFile.writerow(row)
row = None
rows = None
```